# Add new column to DataGridView and Set new Value in run time

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a field in my table with name (Kind) .it's type is int and, i give 0 and 1 values in app.now i want bind my datagridview with this table,and i want to add new columns (with this name:msg) to my datagridview ,that if kind=0 ,msg column (the cell value) will be "Manual",
and if kind=1 ,msg column (the cell value) will be "Database" for example.
output of datagridview will be like:

```
      Kind       msg
   ----------------------- 
       0        Manual
       1       Database
       0        Manual
```

which instruction i should write to get this goal?
i mean how can i add a new column to datagridview and how can i set value to each cells?
thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data source is a `System.Data.DataTable`, then you could make use of [expression columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28VS.71%29.aspx).

You'll have to decide whether that is an acceptable solution, and you'll also have to identify a suitable place within your code to add an expression column to your DataTable, but your code would look something like this:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("msg", typeof(string), "IIF(Kind = 0, 'Manual', IIF(Kind = 1, 'Database', 'Unknown'))");
```

Comment: i write this code but this error occured:"The expression contains undefined function call IFF()".